# Can installed applications bypass vpn and know your real ip?

Tags: vpn, ip, wireguard

Adding that the vpn has an hard kill switch enabled that doesn't allow connections other than through it.

Comment: Applications can use local device data and get your real IP, too.

Comment: Are you using a generic VPN setup, or something like Whonix actually designed to protect against that kind of attack?